# Suggest who I should follow, based on the people that follow me, follow themselves

Tags: mysql

I can't event summarise the question in English too well, so converting to SQL is baffling me.

I have a user table and a follow table

```
USER
id | first_name | last_name
10 | Homer      | Simpson
12 | Marge      | Simpson
14 | Bart       | Simpson
16 | Lisa       | Simpson

FOLLOW
id | follow_id | follower_id | status
1  | 10        | 12          | APPROVED
2  | 10        | 14          | APPROVED
3  | 16        | 12          | APPROVED
4  | 16        | 14          | APPROVED
```

Basically, I want to suggest to a user, other people he may want to follow.

I'm going to base this on:

- find all the people following me and if I'm not already following them, suggest I do follow them
- from that first list (that follow me), find all the people that they follow
- for each of those, suggest that I follow those persons (if I'm not already doing so)

Is anybody able to help me in the right direction?

In the above example data

- Homer is already being followed by Marge and Bart
- In turn, Marge is following Lisa (and Bart is also following Lisa)

So, in this example, I would like to suggest to **Homer** to follow:

- Marge (because she is following him)
- Bart (because he is following him)
- Lisa (because she is being followed by Marge)

WITH THE HELP FROM RICHARD, THIS IS THE FINAL SOLUTION (AS A STORED PROC)

The only addition being the removal of users that are already being followed.

```
BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID,first_name,last_name FROM
    (
        #Users that are following me
        SELECT u.id as ID, u.first_name , u.last_name 
        FROM mchq_user u
        INNER JOIN follow AS f ON u.id = f.follower_id
        WHERE f.follow_id = in_userID
        UNION

        #Users followed by followers of me
        SELECT  f2.follow_id as ID, u2.first_name, u2.last_name
        FROM mchq_user u
        INNER JOIN follow AS f ON u.id = f.follower_id
        INNER JOIN follow AS f2 ON f2.follower_id = u.id
        INNER JOIN mchq_user AS u2 ON u2.id = f2.follow_id
        WHERE f.follow_id = in_userID AND f2.follow_id != in_userID
    ) AS t1
    WHERE t1.Id NOT IN (
        # Users that I follow already
        SELECT u.id
        FROM mchq_user u
        INNER JOIN follow AS f ON u.id = f.follow_id
        WHERE f.follower_id = in_userID
    );
END
```

Comment: Do you have a sql query or any work you've already done to look at and offer advice on?   "Is anybody able to help me in the right direction?" isn't a detailed question or description of the problem you're having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #user (id INT, first_name VARCHAR(50), last_name VARCHAR(50 ))
CREATE TABLE #follow (user_id INT, following_id INT, f_status VARCHAR(50))


INSERT INTO #user ( id, first_name, last_name )
SELECT 10, 'Homer','Simpson' UNION ALL
SELECT 12, 'Marge','Simpson' UNION ALL
SELECT 14, 'Bart','Simpson'  UNION ALL
SELECT 16, 'Lisa','Simpson'

INSERT INTO #follow ( user_id, following_id, f_status )
SELECT  12  ,   10   , 'APPROVED' union all
SELECT  14  ,   10   , 'APPROVED' union all
SELECT  12  ,   16   , 'APPROVED' union all
SELECT  14  ,   16   , 'APPROVED'   

-- Usrs that follow Homer
SELECT id, first_name , last_name 
FROM #user u
INNER JOIN  #follow AS F ON u.id = F.user_id
WHERE f.following_id = 10
UNION
-- Users followed by followers of Homer
SELECT  F2.following_id, u2.first_name, U2.last_name
FROM #user u
INNER JOIN #follow AS F ON u.id = F.user_id 
INNER JOIN #follow AS F2 ON F2.user_id = u.id
INNER JOIN #user AS U2 ON U2.id = F2.following_id
WHERE f.following_id = 10 AND F2.following_id != 10



DROP TABLE #follow
DROP TABLE #user
```

Comment: Thanks Ricardo.  That worked as described especially once I figured out that your column naming convention was the opposite to the model I had in my head.

Comment: @RobinM Glad to help. The whole things can be a dizzy one. Sorry I forgot to comment you on the column changes.

Answer (score 1):

Could be you need a subquery for the follow

```
select distinct a.follower_id, b.first_name, b.last_name from follower as a
inner join user as b on b.id =a.follower_id
where follow_id in   (select follower_id 
                             from follow 
                         where follow_id = '10' and status = 'APPROVED');
```

Comment: What about the followers of your user that follow people who you aren't currently following? You're basically providing people who have followed your user and have already been accepted.  You have no way of telling who that person is following or not following in this query.